# How to change the Visual Studio 2019 Workspace to a new domain name account

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019

Sorry if this is worded incorrectly, but here goes.  The company I work at, added a brand new domain server, taking the old one offline, effectively changing domains from CompanyName/username, to CompanyNamePro/username.  So for me, my existing TFS's WorkSpace was setup for CompanyName/username.  Well, that is gone now.  So when I attempt to edit my WorkSpace to the new CompanyNamePro/username, TFS shows me my old CompanyName/username as already using that Workspace.  HOW do I change that? (even if the change involves manually changing a file somewhere)  (i had code still checked out when the domain server changed)

I have tried a few things:

1. Copying the mapped folder to another folder, then mapping to it, but it didn't work correctly.
2. Tried creating a brand new folder, then mapping to that.  This works, but upon Getting Specific in TFS, it insists that I already have all the code...even though my folder is blank.

I'd much rather somehow change the existing domain mapping to my old huge source code folder.  Somebody must know how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you need to map the new WorkSpace to the Old folder? If yes, you could try the answer. Feel free to let me know if it could give you some help.

Comment: Sorry, I was on vacation last week.  I responded to your suggestion below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove the old workspace mapping for the folder. Then you could map the new workspace to the folder again.

Here are the steps

1. Open **Team Explore -> Source Control Explorer**.
2. Select the **Old workspace**.

[image: WorkSpcae]

3.Right Click the Project and select `Advanced -> Remove Mapping...`

[image: Remove]

Then the folder mapping of the old Workspace will be removed.  You could map the same folder to the new WorkSpace again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work.  It removes the old mapping fine.  But when I assign the new mapping, it tells me: 
The path D:\CompanyName is already mapped in workspace MX00101;CompanyName\jhansen

I have to wonder where that workspace path is stored, so maybe I can change it manually.

Comment: I finally stopped trying to do this with VS 2019, and tried it instead with VS 2017, where it worked immediately without issue.  VS 2019 has given me a couple other odd issues over the past year, none of which I documented of course.  This is why I keep VS 2017 handy.